# Changing screens in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, screen

In my WP7 game I have a menu screen that remembers information so I leave it going and just create a new game level screen (it's a tower defense so the game is segmented into levels) that is shown over the top of the menu screen. Then when you beat that level I call this.ExitScreen(); (and have also tried ScreenManager.RemoveScreen(this);). It removes that level screen and shows the menu again but I see a flash of purple which is just the default color or the null background or however you want to put it. I don't understand why that purple is flashing. Should my menu screen be right below? I'd be grateful for any help understand what's going on here.

Comment: Are you using the GameStateManagament sample from the App Hub site? XNA doesn't have any screen management built in, so you're going to have to explain a bit more about what sample code you're using so we can zero in on what might be going on.

Comment: Yes, I'm usimg the GameStateManagement sample to create screens and add them to the screen manager. If there's multiple screens there must be some sort of order to which they're displayed? Adding the second screen it seemed to appear over my menu screen. I assumed it kept these screens in sort of a list? Maybe I'm not understanding correctly how it handles the screens if you add multiple.

Comment: If you download the Xbox version of the GameStateManagment sample, they've got some pretty good documentation included that should help explain how it works. Not sure why they don't include it in the WP7 version

Comment: Well since I was passing the menu screen into the level anyway to know what upgrades the player had done, I just decided to kill the menu and then recreate a new copy of it exactly as was passed in. Now it doesn't flicker purple. Don't ask me why it's fine with creating a new screen and had problems with the one already there.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not good in c# but i cat help you :)

make (int screen=0)

in draw make cases

```
switch(screen){
    case 0:
    makeMenu();
    break;
    case 1:
    makeGame();
    break;
}
```

and in update

```
switch(screen){
    case 0:
    if(clickPlay){
        screen=1;
    }
    break;
    case 1:
    Game();
    break;
}
```